# Implementation of stack using numpy in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, stack

Like there are implementation of stack using array in c++ I was wondering if the same can be done in python using numpy stack? This was my take on it

```py
from turtle import shape
import numpy as np


class stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = np.empty(shape=(1,100),like=np.empty_like)
        self.n = 100
        self.top = -1

    def push(self, element):
        if (self.top >= self.n - 1):
            print("Stack overflow")
        else:
            self.top = self.top + 1
            self.stack[self.top] = element

    def pop(self):
        if (self.top <= -1):
            print("Stack Underflow")
        else:
            print("Popped element: ", self.stack[self.top])
            self.top = self.top - 1

    def display(self):
        if (self.top >= 0):
            print("Stack elements are: ")
            i = self.top
            while i >= 0:
                print(self.stack[i], end=", ")
                i = i - 1
        else:
            print("The stack is empty")

    def gettop(self):
        if (self.top <= -1):
            print("Empty stack")
        else:
            print("Top: ", self.stack[self.top])

    def isEmpty(self):
        if (self.top == -1):
            print("Stack is Empty")
        else:
            print("Stack is not empty")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = stack()
    ch = 0
    val = 0
    print("1) Push in stack")
    print("2) Pop from stack")
    print("3) Get Top")
    print("4) Check if Empty")
    print("5) Display Stack")
    print("6) Exit")

    while (ch != 6):
        ch = int(input("Enter Choice: "))
        print(ch)
        if (ch == 1):
            val = input("Enter the value to be pushed: ")
            s.push(val)
        elif (ch == 2):
            s.pop()
        elif (ch == 3):
            s.gettop()
        elif (ch == 4):
            s.isEmpty()
        elif (ch == 5):
            s.display()
        elif (ch == 6):
            print("Exit")
        else:
            print("Invalid Choice")
```

But I am stuck at the creation of stack at the start. It produces a stack with 12 all over when I try to push any element into the array.

And I do know that there are much simpler implementation of the same in python but I was curious if it is possible or not.

Comment: I have a problem running your code. In the __init__ method, np.empty_like should have an array as argument, otherwise a `TypeError: The 'like' argument must be an array-like that implements the '__array_function__' protocol. `exception occurs. Am I wrong? Is the like parameter necessary for the initialisation of the stack?

Comment: @Sbunzini Ah yes now that I see I copied the wrong code in, I shall edit it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed around with the code for a while and I found a way to do it, and here it is:

```py
"""
Time: 15:08
Date: 16-02-2022
"""
from turtle import shape
import numpy as np


class stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
        self.n = 10
        self.top = -1

    def push(self, element):
        if (self.top >= self.n - 1):
            print("Stack overflow")
        else:
            self.top = self.top + 1
            self.stack[self.top] = element

    def pop(self):
        if (self.top <= -1):
            print("Stack Underflow")
        else:
            print("Popped element: ", self.stack[self.top])
            self.top = self.top - 1

    def display(self):
        if (self.top >= 0):
            print("Stack elements are: ")
            i = self.top
            while i >= 0:
                print(self.stack[i], end=", ")
                i = i - 1
            print("")
        else:
            print("The stack is empty")

    def gettop(self):
        if (self.top <= -1):
            print("Empty stack")
        else:
            print("Top: ", self.stack[self.top])

    def isEmpty(self):
        if (self.top == -1):
            print("Stack is Empty")
        else:
            print("Stack is not empty")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = stack()
    ch = 0
    val = 0
    print("1) Push in stack")
    print("2) Pop from stack")
    print("3) Get Top")
    print("4) Check if Empty")
    print("5) Display Stack")
    print("6) Exit")

    while (ch != 6):
        ch = int(input("Enter Choice: "))
        print(ch)
        if (ch == 1):
            val = input("Enter the value to be pushed: ")
            s.push(val)
        elif (ch == 2):
            s.pop()
        elif (ch == 3):
            s.gettop()
        elif (ch == 4):
            s.isEmpty()
        elif (ch == 5):
            s.display()
        elif (ch == 6):
            print("Exit")
        else:
            print("Invalid Choice")
```